# How to get all checkboxes in an array in jQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the following dataTable that gets data using ajax with 4 column for checkboxes. The last column selects all checkboxes.

[image]

For each row, every checkbox column has the following element:

1. `<input data-type="col1" data-id="123" type="checkbox">`
2. `<input data-type="col2" data-id="123" type="checkbox">`
3. `<input data-type="col3" data-id="123" type="checkbox">`
4. `<input data-type="all" data-id="123" type="checkbox">`

The `Id= 123` is the row ID.

Now when I go and page the grid I need to pass to server all the values that were checked so I can store them temporarily so if I go previous I can show them again.

This is the code that I have when paging happens:

```
 if (typeof dataTable != 'undefined') {
     $("input:checked", dataTable.rows().nodes()).each(function() {
         console.log($(this).val()); 
     });
 }
```

What I would like to get is an array like this:

```
[
{'id': 123, 'col1': true, 'col2': true, 'col3': false},
{'id': 332, 'col1': true, 'col2': true, 'col3': true}, 
{'id': 401, 'col1': false, 'col2': true, 'col3': false},
...
]
```

How can I get that, or maybe there is an easier way?

Comment: So you mean even if one check box is selected you need the whole row data.. ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with this for a little while and if I understand your reasoning correctly you're trying to get a reference to the current page before paging occurs in order to store the state of the data so it isn't lost? I've n ot figured out a way of intercepting the paging event, only of listening to it and calling a function after it has fired and after the table has redrawn, though I'll continue looking. In the meantime, I've come up with a way of maintaining your data between page loads - by storing it in the raw data of the table. Given this table structure:

```
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>One</th>
      <th>Two</th>
      <th>Three</th>
      <th>Four</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>false</td>
      <td>false</td>
      <td>false</td>
      <td>false</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Mainy more rows -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then this code:

```
  var example = $("#example").DataTable({
    columns: [
      null, {
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          var input = $("<input/>", {
            "data-type": "col1",
            "data-id": row[0],
            "type": "checkbox",
          });
          if (data === "true") {
            input.attr("checked", "checked");
          }
          return input.prop("outerHTML");
        }
      }, {
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          var input = $("<input/>", {
            "data-type": "col2",
            "data-id": row[0],
            "type": "checkbox",
          });
          if (data === "true") {
            input.attr("checked", "checked");
          }
          return input.prop("outerHTML");
        }
      }, {
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          var input = $("<input/>", {
            "data-type": "col3",
            "data-id": row[0],
            "type": "checkbox",
          });
          if (data === "true") {
            input.attr("checked", "checked");
          }
          return input.prop("outerHTML");
        }
      }, {
        render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
          var input = $("<input/>", {
            "data-type": "all",
            "data-id": row[0],
            "type": "checkbox"
          });
          if (data === "true") {
            input.attr("checked", "checked");
          }
          return input.prop("outerHTML");
        }
      }

    ]
  });
  $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td', function() {
    if ($(this).find("input").length) {
      var cell = example.cell(this);
      cell.data($(this).find("input").prop("checked").toString());
      var rowData = example.row($(this).closest("tr")).data();
      if ($(this).find("input").data("type") === "all") {
        if ($(this).find("input").prop("checked").toString() === "true") {
          example.row($(this).closest("tr")).data([rowData[0], "true", "true", "true", "true"]);
        } else {
          example.row($(this).closest("tr")).data([rowData[0], "false", "false", "false", "false"]);
        }
      } else {
        if ((rowData[1] === "true") && (rowData[2] === "true") && (rowData[3] === "true")) {
          example.row($(this).closest("tr")).data([rowData[0], rowData[1], rowData[2], rowData[3], "true"]);
        } else {
          example.row($(this).closest("tr")).data([rowData[0], rowData[1], rowData[2], rowData[3], "false"]);
        }
      }
      example.draw(false);
    }
  });
  $('#example').on('page.dt', function() {
    var dataObject = [];
    example.rows().data().each(function(k, v){
      var rowData = example.row(v).data();
      dataObject.push(
        {
          'id': rowData[0], 
          'col1': rowData[1], 
          'col2': rowData[2], 
          'col3': rowData[3]
        }
      )
    });
    console.log(dataObject);
  });
```

Will store your data between paging events. Your use case might be different though so do bear in mind that render function might need to change. I'll keep on looking for a before paging event but this should fulfil your needs if I've understood them correctly? Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/7zj3dum0/).

p.s. I'm not sure that this is an **answer** to the question as it is stated, merely my stumbling towards one.